# JBoss connection pool creating many connections to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jboss, connection-pooling

We are using a setup of JBoss 4.2.2.GA / Hibernate 3.2.4.sp1 / SpringMVC 2.5 / MySQL 5.0.27.

Below is the mysql-ds.xml file:

```
<datasources>
  <local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>myDS</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/database?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;useConfigs=maxPerformance</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
    <user-name>user</user-name>
    <password>password<password>
    <exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>
    <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
    <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
    <blocking-timeout-millis>30000</blocking-timeout-millis>
    <idle-timeout-minutes>1</idle-timeout-minutes>
    <metadata>
       <type-mapping>mySQL</type-mapping>
    </metadata>
  </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

Looking at the JMX-Console -> service=ManagedConnectionPool, we are using `JBossManagedConnectionPool`.

Now, the problem is that even with mediocre traffic (site attracted approx 5000 Visits / 15000 pageViews yesterday), there are 96 threads in sleep mode on MySQL (got using `show processlist`).

These do get reduced in time but my real question is, why is jboss creating so many connections? MaxConnections on MySQL = 250.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: MySQL just crashed due to 'Too Many Connections'. This is high-priority now so plz any help will do... Also, as per Zoltan's comment, isn't it the connection pool's job to manage my sessions?? How else will I be able to reuse connections? If it helps, I can give a brief view into how the code is setup in my app & is being used!!

Comment: hmm no replies so far??? We need to fix this asap!! Plz help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much analysis, it was discovered that Hibernate was issuing too many queries in the back-end to load certain mappings, as `mysqladmin status` command gives 500 queries / sec.

Resolving this should resolve this problem as well.

Thanks to everyone who helped...

Answer (score 1):

When I experienced this, the problem was that some hibernate sessions were not closed and this cause connection leak. Check that your session close statements are in finally block.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, we are using try / catch / finally blocks like... `UserTransaction trans = null`, `trans = transactionManager.getUserTransaction();trans.begin();` in try, `trans.rollback()` in catch & `if (trans != null && trans.getStatus() == Status.STATUS_ACTIVE) {try.commit();}` in finally.

Comment: BTW.. we are injecting transactionManager into all our services & sessionFactory into our dao, but aren't explicitly using `session.flush() or session.close()`

Comment: The session won't be closed in every case if JBoss manages the connection. See: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/sessionsandtransactions

Comment: I assure you we are only using `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` and not `sessionFactory.openSession()` so as per the link, sessions should be flushing & closing automatically!!